# bootloader - load 2nd stage - qemu works, real machine doesn't

Tags: nasm, qemu, bootloader, bare-metal, real-mode

As a learning exercise, I wrote a little [16 bit bootloader for x86](https://github.com/jameslaydigital/bootsect) bios systems.  It
seemed to work fine on *QEMU*.  I dd'ed it to a drive for an old
amd-turion computer (x86_64), and when I tried to boot that computer,
it would do the BIOS screen, then I just get a blinking cursor on a
black screen.

My question is, what could be different between *QEMU*'s x86 emulator
and a real x86 (64 bit) computer that definitely uses BIOS and not
UEFI?  Do I have to write my code differently for a real computer than
than that of *QEMU*?  Is it the way I'm copying the information to the drive?  Is the computer employing some hardware-level security provision?

I have learned that it doesn't work on VirtualBox either.

It appears that loading the 2nd stage is problematic *(by printing a char from the first stage successfully on real hardware)*.

My first stage bootloader uses code in these files:

**stage_one.asm**

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
LOAD_ADDR: equ 0x9000   ; This is where I'm loading the 2nd stage in RAM.
start:
    xor ax, ax          ; nullify ax so we can set 
    mov ds, ax          ; ds to 0
    mov sp, bp          ; relatively out of the way
    mov bp, 0x8000      ; set up the stack
    call disk_load      ; load the new instructions
                        ; at 0x9000
    jmp LOAD_ADDR
%include "disk_load.asm"
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55 ;; end of bootsector
```

**disk_load.asm**

```
; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
disk_load :

    mov ah, 0x02            ;read from disk
    mov al, [num_sectors]   ;read sector(s)

    mov bx, 0
    mov es, bx

    mov ch, 0x00    ;track 0
    mov cl, 0x02    ;start from 2nd sector
    mov dh, 0x00    ;head 0
    mov dl, 0x80    ;HDD 1

    mov bx, LOAD_ADDR  ;Where we read to in RAM.
    int 0x13        ; BIOS interrupt

    jc disk_error   ; Jump if error ( i.e. carry flag set )

    cmp al, [num_sectors]   ; if num read != num expected
        jne disk_error      ; display error message

    mov ax, READ_SUCCESS
    call print_string
    ret

disk_error :
    mov ax, DISK_ERROR_MSG
    call print_string

    ; Get the status of the last operation.
    xor ax, ax      ; nullify ax
    mov ah, 0x01    ; status fxn
    ;mov dl, 0x80    ; 0x80 is our drive
    int 0x13        ; call fxn

    ;mov ah, 0       ; when we print ax, we only care about the status, 
                    ; which is in al. So, we probably want to nullify
                    ; 'ah' to prevent confusion.

    call print_hex  ; print resulting status msg.
    jmp $

status_error:
    mov ax, STATUS_ERROR
    call print_string
    jmp $

num_sectors: db 0x01

; Variables
DISK_ERROR_MSG: db "Disk read error: status = " , 0
STATUS_ERROR: db 'status failed.', 0
READ_SUCCESS: db 'Read success! ', 0

;AH  02h
;AL  Sectors To Read Count
;CH  Cylinder
;CL  Sector
;DH  Head
;DL  Drive
;ES:BX   Buffer Address Pointer

%include "print.asm"
```

**print.asm**

```
print_char:
    pusha
        mov ah, 0x0e
        int 0x10
    popa
    ret

print_string:
    pusha           ; preserve the registers 
                    ; on the stack.
    mov bx, ax
    print_string_loop:
        mov al, [bx]            ;move buffer index to al
        cmp al, 0               ;if [[ al == 0 ]]; then
        je print_string_end    ;   goto print_string_end
        inc bx                  ;else bx++
        call print_char
        jmp print_string_loop  ;   goto print_string_loop

    print_string_end:
    popa
    ret

print_hex_char:
    pusha
    print_hex_loop:

        ;print a single hex digit
        cmp al, 0x9
        jg a_thru_f
        zero_thru_nine:
            add al, '0'
            call print_char
            jmp print_hex_char_end
        a_thru_f:
            add al, 'A'-0xA
            call print_char

    print_hex_char_end:
    popa
    ret

print_hex:

    pusha

        ;note on little-endianness:
        ;   If you store 1234 in AX,
        ;   4 is the LSB, therefore:
        ;   AH = 12
        ;   AL = 34
        ;
        ;   Moral of the story --
        ;   If you print, you need to
        ;   print AH first.


        mov bl, al
        and bl, 0xF

        mov bh, al
        shr bh, 4
        and bh, 0xF

        mov cl, ah
        and cl, 0xF

        mov ch, ah
        shr ch, 4
        and ch, 0xF

        mov al, '0'
        call print_char

        mov al, 'x'
        call print_char

        mov al, ch
        call print_hex_char

        mov al, cl
        call print_hex_char

        mov al, bh
        call print_hex_char

        mov al, bl
        call print_hex_char

        mov al, ' '
        call print_char

    popa
    ret
```

I generate my kernel like this:

```
nasm -f bin -o stage1.bin stage_one.asm && \
nasm -f bin -o stage2.bin stage_two.asm && \
cat stage1.bin stage2.bin > raw.bin && \
#(mkdir cdiso || :) && \
#cp stage1.bin cdiso && cp stage2.bin cdiso && \
#mkisofs -o raw.iso -b stage1.bin cdiso/
qemu-system-x86_64 raw.bin || \
echo "COULD NOT FINISH ASSEMBLING." &>/dev/stderr
```

Comment: `old` and `x86_64` in the same sentence? You young whippersnappers are spoilt nowadays :-)

Comment: I have cleaned up your question and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the bug that was causing my code to fail.

The problem was when using `int 13h` to read from the hard drive. In *QEMU*, the disk's device number is always `0x80`, so I was hard-coding that into register `dl`, thinking that was the standard hard-drive designation.  As it turns out, BIOS conveniently automatically sets the `dl` register to the drive number that it is trying to boot from, so by commenting out the hard-coded part, I was able to get it working both on *QEMU* and real hardware.

To fix the issue I removed(commented out) this line in the file *disk_load.asm*:

```
mov dl, 0x80    ;HDD 1
```

Comment: I'm very glad you got it going. I do have some general tips for bootloaders in this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) that may or not be of use. I did notice that in your code you did `mov sp, bp`  `mov bp, 0x8000` . You really need to be setting the *SS* segment register and *SP* register with a value. Both of those are what define the stack *SS:SP* . _BP_ is usually related to stackframes but in bootloaders like this you won't need to set it unless a BIOS call requires it to be a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly enabling real mode by setting the 0th bit of the control register to 0 could potentially solve this problem (untested).

```
cli
mov al, cr0
mov bl, 1
not bl
and al, bl
mov cr0, al
sli
```

Comment: It appears to be running in real mode. I just found out that the first stage is running successfully. Added an update to the question.

Comment: You've got a typo in your code. Change `sli` into `STI`.

Comment: Why so many instructions? All it takes is `mov eax,cr0` `and al,-2` `mov cr0,eax`.

Comment: The computer ALWAYS automatically starts in real mode.